Help with a Calculus 2 question about integrals and using the Fundamental theorem of Calculus
I've been given this homework assignment:
Let $a\geq 0$ and let $g(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a, \infty)$ such that for all $x\geq a$:
$$\left|\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt \right|\leq C$$
For some constant $C$. Let $f(x)$ be a function with a continuous derivative on interval $[a,b]$. Prove that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(nx)dx=0$$
I am not sure how to start working on this and would like a hint.
Also, I know that there are some versions of the Fundamental theorem of calculus, so the one we learned goes like this:
Let $f$ be (Riemann) integrable on $[a,b]$. Let $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f$. Therefore, if $f$ is continuous on $x_0$ then $F$ is differentiable on $x_0$ and $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.
Many thanks to the helpers!

What's $n$ in the first equation?

Whoops. There isn't supposed to be one. Fixed

In the second formula, the absolute value is irrelevant.

Yea, fixes that too. Sorry for the overlooks.

HINT: Have you considered integration by parts?

I have tried it. It didn’t get me far, since I’m still left with an integral of a prodct: $\int_{a}^{b}f’(x)g(nx)dx$ (this is the integral of $u’v$ part in integration by parts).
